# Regex replace in JavaScript for escaping special characters enclosed in single quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

In my JavaScript file, I have a variable which takes values like the following

```
stringToBeReplaced = input[name='Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'']

stringToBeReplaced = input[name='They Don't Care About Us']

stringToBeReplaced = input[name='Workin' Day & Night']
```

The pattern will be always like `input[name='*']` with * could be anything.
What I am trying to achieve is to escape only the single quotes and ampersand (' &) appearing in the * field without escaping the enclosing  single quotes using regex replace.

The regex I have formed so far is as follows and what is still pending is to ignore the first single quote from the above pattern. i.e the the single quote preceded by = sign

```
stringToBeReplaced.replace(/((['&])(?!\]))/g,'\\$1'));
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help a lot if you show an example of what was the old values, and what is the desired output of that particular example

Comment: Also, could you explain a bit more about the overall context. Where are these strings--which appear to be CSS selectors--coming from? And why are you apparently using the `name` attribute as a kind of title or description? Can you do the escaping at an earlier point in time, before you have the entire `input[name=]` string? Why do you think you need to escape the `&`?

Comment: Basically jQuery.find method fails in our application which used to work earlier with jQuery 1.8(I am not sure if this has something to do with an upgraded jQuery 1.11 being used now). & is not really required, but just included the regex to support multiple special characters.

Comment: Get the jQuery.find to work, then tinker with the regex

Comment: I agree that it would be the best solution, however that involves a lot of code changes  in the huge framework which is beyond our scope now :-(

Comment: @Ahmad- please find it here  http://regexr.com/3f5db

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
(?<!=)(['&])(?!])
```

`(?<!=)` Negative look behind for `=`

`(['&])` Select the desired characters in character class and capture in group

`(?!])` Negative look ahead for closing `]`

Replace with:

`\` and captured group

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/CQbwtF/5

Comment: Thanks for dissecting it. However this is a php regex and does not seem to be valid for JS